# How to merge the lines in Unix (Sun Solaris) in a specific pattern

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have below *n* number of lines in a flat file:

```
uk,1234560000
uk,6789067000
uk,4567890000
.
.
.
n lines
```

Now I have to make it in below format:

```
uk,1234560000-1234560000,6789067000-6789067000,4567890000-4567890000,......
```

How can I do this transformation?

Comment: these are lines

Comment: uk,1234560000 uk,6789067000 uk,4567890000 . . . n lines

Answer (score 1):

Starting with this file:

```
$ cat file
uk,1234560000
uk,6789067000
uk,4567890000
```

If the formatting in the question is correct, I believe that this does what you ask:

```
$ awk -F, '1==NR{printf "%s",$1} {printf ",%s-%s",$2,$2} END{print""}' file
uk,1234560000-1234560000,6789067000-6789067000,4567890000-4567890000
```

#### How it works

awk will read in a record (line) at a time.  Each line is divided into fields.  With this sample file and a comma as the field separator, the first field, called `$1`, is always `uk` and the second field, called `$2`, is the number.

- `-F,`

  This makes awk treat a comma as a field separator.
- `1==NR{printf "%s",$1}`

  `NR` is the number of lines read so far.  When `1 == NR`, we are on the first line.  When we are on the first line, this tells awk to print the first field, `uk`.
- `printf ",%s-%s",$2,$2`

  For all lines, this tells awk to print a comma followed by the second field, a dash, and the second field again.
- `END{print""}`

  When we reach the end of the file, this tells awk to print a newline.

Comment: Thanks a lot John. it is working absolutely fine. But i request you to can u please make me understand this command.

Comment: @Montu  Please see the updated answer and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks John . now it is crystal clear how it is working.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. 
Here’s one using only the shell (no external programs):

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=, read -r f1 f2
printf "%s,%s-%s" "$f1" "$f2" "$f2"
while IFS=, read -r f1 f2
do
    printf ",%s-%s" "$f2" "$f2"
done
printf "\n"
```

Put the above into a file called, say, `myscript.sh`, do `chmod +x myscript.sh`,
and then run `./myscript.sh` with input and output redirected wherever you want.

The code is simple

- Read two fields, separated by a `,`. 
  Write out field1 `,` field2 `-` field2, *not* terminated by a newline.
- While not at the end of the file, read two fields, separated by a `,`. 
  Write out the second one twice, preceded by a `,`, separated by a `-`,
  and not terminated by a newline.
- After we’ve read the entire file (reached the end of file), write a newline.